# how can I copy files which are stored in one variable

Tags: shell-script, cp

I have the following code.

```
PF=opt/N*.properties
```

Inside PF I have 2 values `/OPT/NA.properties` and `/OPT/NA2.properties`.

How can I copy these 2 files to other location in shell script

```
cp $PF /opt/backup/
```

Answer (score 5):

Based solely on your example, a simple `for` loop will suffice.

```
for myfile in ${PF}
do
  cp "${myfile}" /opt/backup/
done
```

Comment: @Manish your array variable should be `PF=(opt/N*.properties)`. From here you'd have to  `for f in "${PF[@]}"; do cp -- "$f" /opt/backup; done`   otherwise you'd be copying the first file only

Answer (score 4):

```
PF=(opt/N*.properties)
cp "${PF[@]}" /opt/backup
```

Skip the for loop and copy all files in a single command, this way the glob creates an array and the shell can expand the elements in the array in the way shown above.

If you still want to use the for loop you can skip the variable declaration and just do `for myfile in opt/N*.properties; do...`

Comment: Should the `FP` in line 1, and the `PF` in line 2 refer to the same variable name (ie. both=`FP`) ?

Comment: @KevinFegan: you're right, silly typo, fixed.